# Install older version oh phpunit on linux through terminal

Tags: php, linux, terminal, phpunit

I am trying to install an older version of phpunit on a linux/vagrant environment that is still using PHP 5.5.9

The current version of phpunit requires PHP 5.6

I would like to use phpunit version 4.8 instead of 5.1

I tried

`composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.8.*"`

but I still get

`This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended.`

I don't see from [phpunit](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html) documentation how to do that through the terminal.

any help appreciated.

-- Thanks.

Comment: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer

Comment: I tried that    composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.8.*"                   but i still get This version of PHPUnit requires PHP 5.6; using the latest version of PHP is highly recommended.

Comment: `composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.8.*"` runs fine here on php 5.5.9

Comment: Try `composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.8.0"`

Comment: @Will `4.8.0` and `4.8.21` have identical set of dependencies, so there is literally no difference between `4.8.*` and `4.8.0`

Comment: So I still need to `wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar` right? because i set up a new vagrant env and only ran `composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.8.0"` and i get `the program 'phpunit' is currently not installed. To run 'phpunit' please ask your administrator to install the package 'phpunit'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invoke PHPUnit after you did `composer global require "phpunit/phpunit=4.8.*"` are you sure that you are actually using `~/.composer/vendor/bin/phpunit` and not a `phpunit` binary you have on your `$PATH`?

Comment: Thank you! When I was running `which phpunit` I was only coming up with `~/usr/bin/phpunit` ; but what you are saying Totally makes sense. Now need to make sure I only have one phpunit in my env. Thank you again!